# How can I resolve the issue of a MySql Database being too large for import?

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have just downloaded a MySql Database from a live setup.  Importing and Exporting from this live setup has not been a problem.

I would like to work on the website, locally.  As such I have downloaded XAMPP and currently looking to import the Database via XAMPP.  When Importing, I am getting the following message:

> You probably tried to upload a file that is too large.

I have gone into the `php.ini` file and increased the following entries as follows:

- max_execution_time=300;
- upload_max_filesize=200M;
- memory_limit=512M;
- post_max_size=800.

Despite these changes, I am still receiving the above issues.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: via xampp shell or wat,which os ur using

Comment: I am using XAMPP on a Windows 7 machine.